# mysql - lock row while updating

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a table which gets lots of calls(about 30/sec) lets call it `service`.

`service` build as the following

```
`id`|`name`|`lastUpdate`|`inUse`|`usedBy`
```

While I change one of the rows I don't want it to be shown in any other select\update statements till the update is finished. 
for example-

session 1:

```
UPDATE `service` SET `inUse`=1, `usedBy`='xxx' 
WHERE `inUse`=0 ORDER BY `lastUpdate` ASC LIMIT 1
```

session 2 :

```
UPDATE `service` SET `inUse`=1, `usedBy`='xxx' 
WHERE `inUse`=0 ORDER BY `lastUpdate` ASC LIMIT 1
```

despite both queries run in same moment I want them to update different rows.

I know there's some articles about this question, but for some reason each one got different answer, probably it changed over the years..
I'm working with doctrine but I don't mind to work with regular mysql solution

Answer (score 1):

> despite both queries run in same moment I want them to update
>   different rows.

NO, right? AFAIK, DML statement like `UPDATE` takes implicit locks on the table/row and so once an `UPDATE` is happening another `UPDATE`/`INSERT` can not take place since it already acquired a exclusive lock on the table.

See [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

Comment: Thanks that's right, though there is something a bit tricky in that documentation maybe I'm not getting it right - 
" InnoDB does not remember the exact WHERE condition, but only knows which index ranges were scanned."
means that the lock is enabled only if the select statement uses the same index as the update one?

Comment: @user2326568, it means that it remembers the index ranges it has scanned to place a lock on those records/rows. As the doc says, you may not have a where in update/delete and irrespective of that an lock will be placed on record level based on the index keys it scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is best practice, but you could lock the table

```
LOCK TABLE `service` WRITE;
UPDATE `service` SET `inUse`=1, `usedBy`='xxx' 
WHERE `inUse`=0 ORDER BY `lastUpdate` ASC LIMIT 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

See [MySQL Docs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)